# Trying to retrieve an Entity using an attribute of the Entity's relationship object as a search criteria in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, predicate

I am using Core Data in my application where I am trying to retrieve entities whose relationship objects attribute match my criteria.  Unfortunately I am stuck here, because I am passing the id for the relationship object, but I am getting an error saying that the criteria I am passing is not being recognized as an attribute of the entity I am querying.

This is true, because my criteria is actually an attribute for the relationship object, and not an attribute of the entity that I am querying itself.  How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
    // Create fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:myEntityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create predicate
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationshipObjectId == %@", relationshipObjectId];//This is where I am having trouble
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    NSArray *items = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if ([items count]>0) {
        return items[0];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
```

Can anyone see what it is I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all related objects whose attribute matches a certain value, you would 
use a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"rel.attr == %@", value]
```

where "rel" is the name of the relationship, and "attr" is the name
of the attribute that should match the value.

Comment: Martins answer about is correct for a to-one relationship. If it's a to-many relationship use "ANY rel.attr == %@"